# Can't get address of child contract

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js, remix

I'm trying to generate contracts and store their address within a parent contract, but I'm running into a weird issue: The deployed contract is not an instance of the child, but one of the parent.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

contract Parent{
  address[] public children;

  function creteChild (uint256[] memory distro)external payable{
    children.push(address(new Child(msg.sender,distro)));
  }
}

contract Child{
   address payable owner;
   uint256[] distribution;
 
   constructor(address payable admin,uint256[] memory distro)public payable{
    owner=admin;
    distribution=distro;
  }
}
```

After deploying the Parent, I can call the `createChild` function, but the the address that gets stored in the `children` array is another `Parent`, instead of a `Child`. Not sure why that is.

Comment: Could not reproduce your issue. It returns the newly created `Child` address in Remix (https://imgur.com/a/y98vByD) - see the difference between the parent address at the top and the `children[0]` item in the bottom. The only thing I had to change to make it work properly was a logical error in definition `uint256 distribution;` to `uint256[] distribution;` so that the code could compile.

Comment: @PetrHejda did you actually load the contract at that address? How do you know it's an instance of a Child? The fact that it's a different address doesn't indicate the type. If you load it (using At Address), it will be another Parent, and herein lies my issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like if you have multiple contracts in the same .sol file, it will show whatever type you have selected here:

[image]